# Как запустить nodemon в бэкграунде, демоном

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, nodemon

В общем хочу прописать npm start в gitlab ci  пишу npm start запускается nodemon  и pipelines  не заверщается естественно. 
Как запустить его в бэкграунде, или рестартнуть если он запущен.

```
nodemon --exec ts-node ./src/app.ts
```